# Video Mixing Options

Tags: gstreamer, jmf, multimedia, mixing, python-gstreamer

I am working on a bigger project of video-wall and want to display multiple sources of videos on a single display.

something like this --

[image]

What are all my options?

1. Java with JMF
2. Python with GStreamer bindings

Before committing to a technology, I want to get a clear picture about available resources and their limitations.

Answer (score 3):

With gstreamer you can realize this. You would use 4 uridecodebin instances and feed them into a videomixer. On each videomixer.pad you can set the xpos,ypos,z-order and alpha. Between the uridecodebins and the videomixer, you probably want to plug scaling and framerate adaptation.

Comment: can i do this with separate video cards, AFAIK, you need URI for using streaming..

Comment: sure, I was just giving a generalized example to get you going